# Fastest way to count combinations of N elements from N different sets with sum less than T

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Given **N** different splits/parts of a route and empirical data on how long these splits take I want to count the number of combinations of split-times (one time from each split) so that the sum of all splits is **less than S**. Just to clarify, every combination has exactly one element from each of the N splits $S_1, ... ,S_N$.

$$
|\{(t_1,...,t_N) \in S_1 \times ... \times S_N | \sum_{i=1}^N t_i < T\}|
$$

An example on what the data looks like (the split-times are ordered low -> high):

### [split_times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHLQI.png)

I already tried the simple approach of iterating over all possible paths, but it's way too slow.

````
while(finished == false){

    //calculate time for that path
    var time = calc_time(path, times);

    //if time < T that path gets added to paths and path becomes the next path
    if(time < T){

      pathcount++;
      path[path.length - 1]++;

    }

    //if time >= T we go to the next path that can be faster
    if(time >= T){

      for(var index = path.length - 1; index >= 0; index--){

        if(index == 0){

          finished = true;
          break;

        }

        if(path[index] == 0) continue;

        if(path[index] > 0){

          path[index] = 0;
          path[index - 1]++;
          break;

        }

      }

    }

    //if some split-index of the path is too big the previous splits get changed
    for(var index = path.length - 1; index > 0; index--){

      if(path[index] == times.length){

        path[index] = 0;

        //change this step to binary search?
        path[index  - 1]++;

      }

    }

    //if first split-index of the path is too big we are finished
    if(path[0] == times.length) finished = true;

  }
```
````

Comment: Have you considered generating functions, and then removing the cases you don't want? (Depends on the type of data)

Comment: Do you really need the exact number? If you don't mind having estimated values, you can run a Monte Carlo simulation and take large enough number of samples to estimate the probability that a random path has your desired property. The simulation algorithm should run linearly.

Comment: @YozefTjandra that's a great idea! I will try that :D